# Bash, syntax error: 'elif' unexpected after elif line

Tags: bash, if-statement

I googling about an hour to find why my bash script is error and i feel my brain is ready to explode cause no answers, please help me

```
dtc=$(df /cache | awk '{print $4}' | awk 'NR==2')
    if [ "$dtc" -gt "196608" ]; then
        echo -ne "|         |  0%|         |\r"
        su -c "/system/0211/installer/swap/0211swaptocache192mb.sh"
        sleep 0.8
        echo -ne "|>>>>>>   | 30%|         |\r"
        mkswap /cache/0211swap.img
        swapon -p 1 /cache/0211swap.img
        echo 100 >  /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
        sleep 0.8
        echo -ne "|>>>>>>>>>| 55%|>        |\r"
        cp /system/0211/installer/swap/0211swapon /system/etc/init.d/0211swapon
        sleep 0.8
        echo -ne "|>>>>>>>>>|100%|>>>>>>>>>|\r"
        chmod 777 /system/etc/init.d/0211swapon
        sleep 1
        echo -ne "|>>>>>>>>>|Done|>>>>>>>>>|\n"
        sleep 0.8
        echo "If nothing wrong, your Swap is 192MB and should active"
        sleep 0.8
        else
        echo "/cache partition: not enough space"
        sleep 0.8
    elif [ "$dtc" -gt "163840" ]; then
        echo -ne "|         |  0%|         |\r" #this is the error
        su -c "/system/0211/installer/swap/0211swaptocache160mb.sh"
        sleep 0.8
        echo -ne "|>>>>>>   | 30%|         |\r"
        mkswap /cache/0211swap.img
        swapon -p 1 /cache/0211swap.img
        echo 100 >  /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
        sleep 0.8
        echo -ne "|>>>>>>>>>| 55%|>        |\r"
        cp /system/0211/installer/swap/0211swapon /system/etc/init.d/0211swapon
        sleep 0.8
        echo -ne "|>>>>>>>>>|100%|>>>>>>>>>|\r"
        chmod 777 /system/etc/init.d/0211swapon
        sleep 1
        echo -ne "|>>>>>>>>>|Done|>>>>>>>>>|\n"
        sleep 0.8
        echo "If nothing wrong, your Swap is 160MB and should active"
        sleep 0.8
    fi
```

Can someone please help me? 'elif' unexpected but the error is at the line after the elif

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: thanks, i can know where is my fault for the entire script

Comment: and where is it ?

Comment: @AhmadFikri: `if` syntax from `help info`: `if COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; [ elif COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; ]... [ else COMMANDS; ] fi`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an `else` in the middle of the `then` section:

```
...
    echo "If nothing wrong, your Swap is 192MB and should active"
    sleep 0.8
    else   # <-- this needs to go *after* the last `elif` section
    echo "/cache partition: not enough space"
    sleep 0.8
elif [ "$dtc" -gt "163840" ]; then
...
```